# Появление контроллера, при добавлении в навигационный стек, с левой стороны?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller

При добавлении нового контроллера в навигационный стек:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

он выезжает справа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы новый контроллер (iOS10+) выезжал с левой стороны? Т.е. нужно изменить только направление появления контроллера. Причем оставить возможность использовать и "правое" появление контроллера тоже. Таббар и навбар должны оставаться "сверху", точно так же как при родной "правой" анимации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения Вашей проблемы есть библиотека [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero). С её помощью Вы сможете добавить в iOS-приложение красивые анимации, в том числе и при создании нового `UIViewController` в `UINavigationController`.

Процесс установки данной библиотеки я описывать не буду, скажу лишь, что через CocoaPods её установить можно. Для работы с Hero добавьте в начало файла с кодом такую строчку:

```
import Hero
```

Затем в месте, где Вы собрались показывать новый `UIViewController`,  настройте анимацию по умолчанию:

```
Hero.shared.defaultAnimation = HeroDefaultAnimationType.cover(direction: .right)
```

А также сообщите о том, что ваш `UINavigationController` собирается использовать библиотеку Hero:

```
self.navigationController?.hero.isEnabled = true
```

Теперь даже при использовании стандартной функции `pushViewController` Вы увидите на экране ожидамый результат:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

На экране будет происходить что-то подобное:

[image: Привер работы на iPod]

Comment: там, похоже, экран перекрывается целиком во всех примерах. Мне же нужно, чтобы и таббар и навбар оставались сверху - так же как при родной "пуш"-анимации ...

Comment: @xhr Ознакомьтесь с обновлённым ответом.

Comment: работает норм ) смущает только, что ради одной анимации требуется добавить дополнительную зависимость в проект. попроще бы это как-то сделать ....

Comment: @xhr Так Вы все анимации с помощью Hero сделайте, тогда их потом будет проще отключить.

Comment: в смысле? зачем мне все анимации делать через Hero? Меня устраивают и стандартные анимации, но вот в одном единственном месте нужно сделать "обратную" анимацию и вот ради этой анимации надо добавить в проект новый pod. Неправильно это как-то ) Неужели нет более простого решения? Но, так все работает, спасибо )

Comment: @xhr Целиком всё Ваше приложение я не видел, но, к примеру, может возникнуть ситуация, что заказчик потребует ускорить все анимации в 2 раза. Если у Вас все анимации реализованы с помощью одной библиотеки, то тогда настроить их будет проще.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
let transition = CATransition.init()
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: это криво работает с очень странной анимацией https://ibb.co/njRSTz